# How to map more than one Attribute with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

If I type in my console

```
u = User.first
u.friends(&map:username)
```

I get `["Peter", "Mary", "Jane"]` but I also want to show the birthday, so how do I do that? I tried

```
u.friends(&map:username, &map:birthday)
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the alternate block syntax:

```
u.friends.map{|f| [f.username, f.birthday]}
```

which would give an array of arrays.

```
u.friends.map{|f| "#{f.username} - #{f.birthday}"}
```

would give you an array of strings. You can do quite a bit from there.

Answer (score 11):

With ActiveRecord >= 4 you can simply use:

```
u.friends.pluck(:username, :birthday)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
u.friends.map {|friend| [friend.username, friend.birthday]}
```

The `&` syntax is simply a shorthand to the underlying Ruby method.